# How to make this expression smaller and more beautiful?

Tags: r

Is is possible to compact this expression in R:

```
for(j in 1:dim(data)[3]) data[,,j] <- f(data[,,j])
```

The `data` variable is 3D-array and `f` accepts and returns 2D-matrix. I need to call `f` on every "matrix" of array of matrices (in fact, `data` is image stored as array of color channels and I get it from function that load image and `f` processes single channel - so, it is not feasible to use alternative representation, I just need to optimize this code).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
a[] <- apply(a, 3, f)
```

or this if you don't want to overwrite `a`:

```
replace(a, TRUE, apply(a, 3, f))
```

For example,

```
f <- function(x) mean(x) * x^0
a <- array(1:24, 2:4)

aa <- replace(a, TRUE, apply(a, 3, f))

for(i in 1:4) a[,,i] <- f(a[,,i])

identical(a, aa)
# [1] TRUE
```